# Two-sided float barrier?

Tags: floats

The `\floatbarrier` command prevents the floats declared before the barrier from moving past the barrier. However, it does not prevent floats declared after the barrier to move before the barrier. How can I define a two-sided barrier that prevents floats from both directions to move past it?

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide the code for a minimal document which produces the problem?

Comment: `\suppressfloats[t]`